# Model transformer and expected form view data mismatch in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I'm in Symfony 4 , When i create a form type
However when I try to view the form, I get the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   App\Entity\Property, but is an instance of class
>   App\Controller\PropertyController. You can avoid this error by setting
>   the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that
>   transforms an instance of class App\Controller\PropertyController to
>   an instance of App\Entity\Property.

```
//   src/Form/PropertyType.php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Property;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class PropertyType extends AbstractType

{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options=null)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('surface')
            ->add('rooms')
            ->add('bedrooms')
            ->add('floor')
            ->add('price')
            ->add('heat')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('address')
            ->add('postal_code')
            ->add('sold')
            ->add('created_at')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Property::class,
        ]);
    }
}


// src/Controller/Admin/AdminPropertyController.php

<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Repository\PropertyRepository;

use App\Controller\PropertyController;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use App\Form\PropertyType;


class AdminPropertyController extends AbstractController 

{

    /**
    * @var PropertyRepository
    */

    private $repository;

     public function __construct (PropertyRepository $repository)
     {
        $this->repository = $repository;
     }

     /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin.property.index")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
     public function index()
     {
        $properties = $this->repository->findAll();
        return $this->render('admin/property/index.html.twig', compact('properties'));
     }

     /**
     *@Route("/admin/{id}", name="admin.property.edit")
     *@param PropertyController $property
     *@return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
     public function edit(PropertyController $property)
     {
        $form = $this->createForm(PropertyType::class, $property);
        return $this->render('admin/property/edit.html.twig', ['property'=>$property, 'form'=>$form->createView() ]);
     }

}

// templates/admin/property/edit.html.twig

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body%}

    <div class="container mt-4">
        <h1>Editer le bien </h1>

        {{ form_start(form) }}

            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Editer</button>

        {{ form_end(form) }}

    </div>  

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: public function edit(PropertyController $property) is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to post a comment, so this will have to be an answer.

The code is Ok in your edit() function, but you should not pass another Controller as an argument.
In fact, in your PropertyController you should use:

```
$response = $this->forward('App\Controller\AdminPropertyController::edit', [
        // your array of parameters goes here
    ]);

return $response;
```

And that's it - don't use Controllers as arguments, just forward to their dedicated functions. This will ensure that they get a Request object with all the needed parameters.
Best of luck, mate - truly mean it.